# AJAX in PHP function is applying to every next instance of the function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here I have an `.ajax` function within a PHP function, like this:

```
function phpFunction($ID) {
    print "<script>
            $('.uparrow').click(function(){
                request = $.ajax({
```

etc... the rest isn't important.

Anyway, the class `.uparrow` is an html element that runs this `.ajax` function when clicked. The other thing you should know is that this function: `phpFunction()` is called a few times in the document, like this:

```
phpFunction(1)
phpFunction(2)
phpFunction(3)
```

However, the problem is that when I load `phpFunction()`, and I click on the `.uparrow` element, the `.ajax` call is made on behalf of each instance of `phpFunction()` that follows the one whose element I clicked on.

So if I clicked on the `.uparrow` of `phpFunction(1)`, I would also be virtually clicking on the `.uparrow`s of `phpFunction(2)` and `phpFunction(3)`. Essentially, I need `.uparrow` to just be a local class that only applies to the instance of `phpFunction()` that is currently being called.

The only solution I could think of is to replace `.uparrow`'s class name with something unique to each call of this function. The only difference between each instance of `phpFunction()` is their input `$ID` and I was thinking I could redefine `.uparrow` as:

```
class = '$ID.uparrow'
```

or

```
class = $ID + 'uparrow'
```

But that doesn't work. So how do I make sure that when I click on `.uparrow` within `phpFunction(1)`, that the `.ajax` function only gets called that one time?

This is pretty confusing to explain and probably to understand, so please tell me if there's something that needs elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a list of  elements, and when you click one of them, you want to do an ajax call.

```
<a href="#" class="uparrow" data-id="<?= $id1 ?>">click me</a>
<a href="#" class="uparrow" data-id="<?= $id1 ?>">click me</a>
<script>
$(function(){ //on DOM ready
   $('.uparrow').on('click', function(){
      //do ajax call
      $.ajax({
          url: 'url here'
          type: 'post|get'
          data: $(this).attr('data-id'), // you only send the ID of the clicked element
          ... callbacks, etc
      })
   });
})
</script>
```

Now you only have a function that makes an ajax call and takes the parameter to send from the element you clicked.

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve

Comment: Not quite what I meant. My problem is that when the function is called, ideally each part of the function is called only once. But instead, when I run the .ajax part, it also gets called for each instance of the phpFunction() that follows. How do I prevent that?

Comment: you dont have to call the phpFUnction many times. Just call it once and do the rest in you view/html part as suggested here

Comment: The PHP function generates a blog post by extracting data from a mySQL table and placing it within html. So I have to run the function multiple times with the input being the row number in the table in order to display all the posts. I didn't want to get too confusing so I left that out. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('[class="uparrow"]').click( function () {

  var request = $.ajax({ 
                 // Your ajax call
               });

});
```

this will execute `ajax` on the clicked element with `.uparrow` class

### HTML

```
<a class="uparrow" href="#" data-ajax="I'm the first element">Click Me</a>
<a class="uparrow" href="#" data-ajax="I'm the second element">Click Me</a>
<a class="uparrow" href="#" data-ajax="I'm the third element">Click Me</a>
```

### JS:

```
$('[class="uparrow"]').click(function () {

    var currentAjax = $(this).data('ajax')
    console.log(currentAjax);

});
```

And the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/6urHz/)

Comment: Not really what I meant. The problem is preventing the `.click` function from running every other .ajax function in the document. When I click on `.uparrow` of phpFunction(1), the .ajax functions of phpFunction(2), phpFunction(3), phpFunction(4), etc. all get called as well.

Comment: The `.data('ajax')` confuses me. 'ajax' is a variable yes? Where is it defined?

Comment: @Adam the `.data('ajax')` and `attr('data-ajax')` refer to two different things. Though it will work the way you have specified but in case of `data attributes` you should use `attr` method.

Comment: @trop `.data('ajax')` gets the value of `data-ajax` attribute

Comment: @AdamAzad Ah gotcha. But the problem isn't that I have multiple instances of a class in a list. I have multiple instances of `phpFunction()`, and when I use an instance of the `.uparrow` class in one `phpFunction()`, it also runs the other functions at the same time (all the functions I am talking about are instances of `phpFunction()`). Refer back to my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Do not call your php function multiple times. Just one time is sufficient.**

Modify the markup of your `.uparrow` element to include the `id` like so:

```
<a class="uparrow" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="#">TextM/a>
```

Then re-write your php function like so:

```
function phpFunction() { /* no need to pass the ID */ ?> 
<script>
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.uparrow', function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: 'URL',
          type: 'POST'.
          data: $(this).attr('data-id')
      })
   });
})
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Call your phpFunction like so:
`phpFunction();`

**UPDATE**

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>trop</title>
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/postStyle.css' />
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,300,200|Homenaje&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel='shortcut icon' href='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/icons8-metro-style/256/Music-Note-icon.png'>
            <script src='../jquery.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='../script.js'></script>
        </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $ids = array(1,2,3); // IDs of the posts you want
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM all_posts WHERE ID IN($ids)"); 
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    ?>
        <div class='post' style='width:470px'>
            <h3><?php echo $data['Title']; ?></h3>
            <div class='date'><?php echo $data['DateTime']; ?></div>
            <iframe width='470' height='300' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/WF34N4gJAKE' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <p><?php echo $data['Body']; ?></p>
            <div class='postmeta1'> 
                <p><a href='<?php echo $data['DownloadLink']; ?>' target='_blank'>DOWNLOAD</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class='verticalLine' style='height:39px'></div>
            <div class='postmeta2'> 
                <p class='uparrow' data-id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>">&#x25B2;</p>
                <div class='votes'>3</div>
                <p class='downarrow'>&#x25BC;</p>
            </div>
            <div class='verticalLine' style='height:39px'></div>
            <div class='postmeta3'> 
                <div class='tags'>
                    <p><?php echo $data['Tags']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <script>
        var request;
        $('.uparrow').click(function(){
            request = $.ajax({
                url: 'votesHandler.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: { add : '1', ID : $(this).attr('data-id') }
                });
                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('Voted!');
                });
                request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(
                        'Oops, something went wrong'
                    );
                });
                request.always(function () {
                    alert('Done.');
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PHP function generates a blog post by extracting data from a mySQL table and placing it within html. So I have to run the function multiple times with the input being the row number in the table in order to display all the posts. I didn't want to get too confusing so I left that out. Sorry!

Comment: Not sure how you are doing it.. post that bit of the code too.

Comment: I ran the code but none of the html showed up in developer tools (probably because it is within `while` loop?)

Comment: i edited the code, can you try again? Make sure you have posts with the given IDS in your DB.

Comment: Nope, still no html :/. Post 1,2, and 3 all exist. I appreciate your efforts though!